# how to add product description,add to cart in the jquery dialog

Tags: jquery

I am using the following code in my shopping site.Now i want to show product title,price ,short description of the product,add to cart button in jquery dialog.The $(#dialog).html ....is not  working .The Error display is ; expected.I think i didn't miss any tags.How do i resolve this.

```
$(function () {
debugger;
$("#dialog").dialog({
modal:true,
autoOpen: false,
resizable: false,
width: "auto"
});

$(".dialogify").bind("click", function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
var producttitle='@Model.DefaultPictureModel.Title';
var productprice='@Model.ProductPrice.Price';
$("#dialog").html("<img src='" + $(this).next().find('img').attr('src') + "' width='150' + height='150'>"+"<h2>"+producttitle+"</h2>"+"<label>"+productprice+"</label>"+"<input type="button"    value="@(Model.ProductPrice.AvailableForPreOrder ? T("ShoppingCart.PreOrder") : T("ShoppingCart.AddToCart"))" class="button-2 product-box-add-to-cart-button"   onclick="AjaxCart.addproducttocart('@addtocartlink ');return false;" />");

$("#dialog").dialog("option", "position", {
modal:"true",
my: "center",
at: "center",
of: window
});
if ($("#dialog").dialog("isOpen") == false) {
$("#dialog").dialog("open");
 }
});
});
```

Comment: show the error whats you are facing.,in console(use chrome browser develoepr tools to find the errors)

Answer (score 0):

The `$('#dialog').html(...` line has the problem. Somewhere. I'm sure. But it's too long, and incredibly unreadable. You should re-write it as:

```
$('<img>').attr('src', $(this).next().find('img').attr('src')).width(150).height(150).appendTo('#dialog');
$('<h2>').text(producttitle).appendTo('#dialog');
$('<label').text(productprice).appendTo('#dialog');
$('<input>').attr('type', 'button').value(@(Model.ProductPrice.AvailableForPreOrder) ? T("ShoppingCart.PreOrder") : T("ShoppingCart.AddToCart")).attr('class', 'button-2 product-box-add-to-cart-button' ).on('click', function(){AjaxCart.addproducttocart('@addtocartlink ');return false;}).appendTo('#dialog');
```

Comment: iam not getting any errors.but if i click the quickview it remains same.

Comment: Could you create a fiddle for this?